# Declarative Authorization (permissions) for Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, cancan, declarative

Preface:
Anyone coming from the Rails community is probably familiar with cancan on the server side for declaring authorization of model actions. IE. can?(:read, Project)

Background: But, in the UI layer on the frontend, I have not found anything that provides the same type of abstraction for handling what users see and what they have permission to do (obviously always have a backend auth layer as well). For example, do you show a button to the user? Do we include a 'contenteditable' element attribute? If a user clicks 'like', do we attempt to register that or do we present them with a login dialogue box?

Question: Does anyone know of a framework/tool/library/best-practice for handling this type of UI issue?

Followup: Does the question get evaluated in the view or in the template? Is this a feature of the template language or a set of boolean variables that we pass in to the template?

Aside:
I had an idea for a cancan imitation tool where the method signature would be something like App.can('like',project,user), where project and user are BB model objects. The issue though might be the number of different actions a user might be able to perform on any given object. IE. like the project, edit the project, comment on the project, invite a friend to the project, etc. Some of these can be reduced to RESTful actions, but I think most would agree the UI presents more types of actions.

Comment: I don't know of any frameworks that do this specifically, but one simple solution would be to just make your "can" object a Backbone.Model, then pass that model to your views (which could use it to check "should I render foo?").

Answer (score 2):

We had the same situation in our project where everything in the page should be shown and hidden according to a permissions given to the user and here is the solution I came up with.

You need to save permissions first in the user and load them in client side; then you can check them as follows

1-Declare the "filterByPermission" function in your base view (all your views should inherit this one)

```
class SampleProject.Views.BaseView extends Backbone.View

  filterByPermission:=>
    #these views will be removed incase user does not have a specific permission
    if @views_permissions?
      for permission, selector of @views_permissions
        unless SampleProject.current_user.has_permission permission
          @$(selector).remove()

    #these views will be removed incase user has a specific permission
    if @remove_views_permissions?
      for permission, selector of @remove_views_permissions
        if SampleProject.current_user.has_permission permission
          @$(selector).remove()
```

2-and then you can come in another view that inherit the base view and define your permissions in the "views_permissions" has (something similar to the events hash)

```
class SampleProject.Views.UsersIndex extends SampleProject.Views.BaseView
  views_permissions:
    "create_users":  "#js_create_user_li, #new_user_modal"
    "import_users": "#js_import_btn_li, #import_form_li"
    "edit_users"  :  "#edit_user_modal"
    "delete_users"  :  "#js_delete_user_li, .js-user-selector-header"

  render:=>
    #render your view here
    @filterByPermission()
```

3-call @filterByPermission() after rendering your view.

This way you'll have one place to control views according to permissions without adding if statements all over your code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what frameworks are out there, but you can have Rails or whatever server-side framework you use render your permissions as `JavaScript` objects.

For instance:

```
var userAuth = { userId: 1234, userType: 'Admin',
                 /** A little more complex permission scenario */
                 privileges: [{ProjectA: 'admin'}, 
                              {ProjectB: 'user'}, 
                              {ProjectC: 'noaccess'}]};
```

So in your view or template, you can declaratively render a piece of UI element based on the permission of the user currently logged in. Using `Underscore` template for example, you can perform some JavaScript logic and checks.

```
/** Operate using a declared variable */
<% if (userAuth.userType === 'Admin') {%>
    <div>This is only shown to admin.</div>
<% } %>

/** OR operate on the actual property on the working model */
<% if (myModelProperty === 'Admin') {%>
    <div>This is only shown to admin.</div>
<% } %>
```

This type of checks can also be done in the actual `View` itself to limit certain functionalities based on the user, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's true that I can do that, but the problem is when those permissions are much more complex than just Admin vs non-Admin. Also, sometimes permissions depends on a complex relationship, for instance you can edit a comment on a project if you are a member of that project with admin privileges.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You can also do another AJAX request to perform additional checks and have the server-side check the permissions. You can also do something like this depending on the complexity of your permissions: `var userAuth = {userId: 1234, privileges: [{ProjectA: 'admin'}, {ProjectB: 'user'}, {ProjectC: 'noaccess'}]};`

Comment: Yes, AJAX requests are another option, but then there is a speed tradeoff. Also, often the client has enough information to answer the permissions question already, but no organized way of asking the question. Of course, all authorization is strongly enforced server-side, but it's best to have a UI that can do this itself. Like soft-validations: https://github.com/n-time/backbone.validations client-side, and strong-validations server-side play nicely together.

Comment: If you have those permissions cached, the speed should be very minimal when doing AJAX. You can also store those permissions ahead of time in cookies.

Comment: How might I dump the permissions to cache/store them? I see this is a feature of cantango, but I'm not using that...